# Manually sending chunked requests

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, windows-phone, httpclient

I'm looking to send chunked data to a network resource from my WP8. Looking in msdn I see the HttpWebRequest class has a [SendChunked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.sendchunked.aspx) property.

Is there something similar available on Windows Phone? I've looked at HttpWebRequest and HttpClient and can only assume I need to send the chunked data manually at this point.

Answer (score 1):

`SendChunked` isn't supported in the [Windows Phone version of HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

This means that you'll need to send the chunks yourself. It's not that hard though if the server already supports receiving chunked data.

Based on experience in this area I'd recommend sending the chunks sequentially and don't try to do multiple chunks at the same time as this makes debugging much harder.

Comment: Thanks, I figured so much. I'd really appreciate it if you could take a look at a related post about created these chunked messages.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172485/creating-vnd-pwg-multiplexed-message

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone HttpWebRequest automatically sends chunk data if (i believe) the data exceeds 256 bytes (?)

In our case the client (Windows Phone) is trying to send an image to the server (Java) and if ever the data is a huge string or an image. It gets chunked and sent to server.

Comment: interesting. I'll have to look into that a little further.